# ElasticSearch - Operational Insights , and Trends

Tags: elasticsearch

Given an ElasticSearch Installation, I want to know current trends and insights. I am not sure if Aggregators would help here.

1. What are the top queries for last 24 hours?
2. Most frequently searched terms in last 24 hours? etc.
3. Most accessed documents in last 24 hours?

Is there any way to collect and get hold of these metrics from ElasticSearch.

A typical use case- As a user visits the homepage, i want to show the trending searches, and top content.

Comment: An [inspiring blog post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/improving-user-intelligence-with-the-elk-stack-at-sca) came out yesterday with pretty much the same points you bring up. The article is high-level but does mention some pointers.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative if you do not want to load your existing ElasticSearch installation with additional metrics is to send this data to a log management solution on the cloud -- such as Loggly, Logentries, etc.